# Automatically close issues in a different redmine subproject

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking

Redmine has the ability to automatically close issues when commit messages are properly formatted, as specified by [Redmine's documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages).

We use this feature a lot, but we've come to the following corner case:

- if the issue and the repository used for the commit belong to the same sub-project, then everything is fine;
- however, in our case we have one project that is divided into several sub-projects (1 for the platform, 1 for the payload, etc.). Then, if the issue is declared inside one sub-project (e.g., application) but then closed by a commit into a different sub-project (e.g., payload), Redmine does not update the status of the issue from the commit message.

Of course, we can still close issues "by hand", but does anyone have a workaround or a specific workflow to automate this case too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable cross project referencing of issues in Administration -> Settings -> Repositories.

The option is labeled "Allow issues of all the other projects to be referenced and fixed"